# MMU: Non-global supervisor page, superfluous?

Tags: riscv

Page 45 of the [Draft Privileged ISA Specification v1.7](http://riscv.org/specifications/privileged-isa/) shows a table of PTE types. I do understand the purpose of the first 8 and of the last 4, which is to save some TLB cache misses on context switch, as far as I understood.

But what are the types from 8 to 11 good for?

In user mode they are unnecessary as you could just set the valid bit to false. And in privileged / supervisor mode you could use the first 8 instead. Supposed you have a different page table for each mode.